# quartz 2d iphone not drawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-2d

i was trying out quartz 2d today and i got to learn basic drawing and other things, but now, somehow everything i do doesn't draw a thing on the iphone screen! i tried making a new project and starting from scratch but still no luck... first, i made a new view based application, and then created a new file (.h and .m) as a subclass of UIView. In the implementation, i just overrode the drawRect method, and nothing happens! heres the code:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

 CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

 CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, red);
 CGContextBeginPath(context);
 CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200);
 CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
 CGContextSetFillColor(context, red);
 CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

i have another project that i started before and have the exact same code in and that runs perfectly... so i think i changed some settings or something.. can anyone help?

EDIT: there is nothing i forgot, im sure of it, since i've been doing what i did in my last project, but somehow, it doesnt draw in this one...

Comment: your drawing code looks ok (maybe you should to set color space as well, but it works anyway), so I'd look for problems somewhere else. For example make sure that you've set your view type properly if you create it using IB. Or make sure that it is visible...

Comment: How are you adding your view to the window?

Comment: Put the breakpoint in the drawRect method. I suspect that your code doesn't run at all

Comment: i just tried adding a label through IB, and it worked. i tried to add a label in the drawRect method and it didn't work... so i think that like vodkhang said, my code doesnt run at all, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually forget to set the class of the custom view in Interface Builder (*Class* popup at the top of the *Identity* page of the *Inspector* window). That would explain why *drawRect:* isn't called.

Comment: What do you mean by custom view? do you mean the viewcontroller that xcode creates or do you mean the subclass of UIView that i created?

Comment: By _custom view_, I mean the subclass of _UIView_ that you created.